# What's this app icon?

Tags: applications, samsung, notification-bar, notification-icons, push-notifications

[image]

Hi I hope anyone can help figure out this app icon on the notification bar. I can't for the life of me know what it is. lol

Comment: If you have Firefox than you've a tab opened in Private Browsing in it. Close Private Browsing and the icon should go away. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-firefox-android

Comment: Thank you so much!!!